# How to tell event handlers to point to dynamically loaded content

Tags: jquery

I'm looking for a solution to the following problem:

1) I'm loading a couple of text lines, some of them containing a link to a footnote like this: 1). These lines are embedded in an <a> element (see below)

2) when the user clicks on such a line, the corresponding footnote text should show up for some seconds

3) in a static context, there is no problem to accomplish this behaviour. However, my problem is that the lines loaded under 1) vary from call to call, and so do the connected footnote texts. Therefore, I'm trying to find a way to dynamically connect the (varying number of) javascript event handler functions to their corresponding footnote texts.

So far, I have managed to come up with the following code - which doesn't work as desired, however:

```
function displayData(data) {
  $('#statisticTable').html(data);  // coming from a datapage.php
  for (i = 0; i < 15; i++) {        // max. 15 footnotes per page
    // The lines containing a hint are looking as follows: 
    // <a href="" id="nt1" class="ui-link">Any Title <sup>1)</sup></a>
    $('#nt' + i).click(function() {
      if (!notesAlreadyLoaded) {
        $.get('notes.php', 'some params', processNotes);
        // a footnote looks like this:
        // <div class="reg_footnote" id="note1">Comment on Any Title: ... </div>
        notesAlreadyLoaded = true;
      }
      else
        // Where can I get the number 'note_index' from?
        // Trying to read the 'id' attribute from the <a> element doesn't work?
        $("#note"+note_index).fadeIn(800).delay(3000).fadeOut(800);
    });
  }
  $.mobile.changePage('#data');
}

function processNotes(notes) {
  $('#footnotes').html(notes);
  // where can I get the number 'note_index' from?
  $("#note"+note_index).fadeIn(800).delay(3000).fadeOut(800);
}
```

Apparently, the event handler functions are created correctly, and they get called in the right moment, too. However, I can't find a way to tell them which footnote they should fade in.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use event delegation. Don't bind events onto the elements themselves, but rather onto an ancestor element that will never be removed or replaced:

```html
<ul id="mylist">
    <li><a href="#" class="foo">Foolink</a></li>
</ul>
```

In the above code we could bind directly to the anchor:

```javascript
$(".foo").on("click", doSomething);
```

But as you pointed out, this doesn't work for new links that may be dropped into the DOM at a later date. As such, we should delegate the job to the parent element:

```javascript
$("#mylist").on("click", ".foo", doSomething);
```

Now the event is bound to the ancestor element, which lets us respond to any anchor click that should happen within it.

When a click event bubbles up to the `#mylist` element, coming from an item that matches our `.foo` selector, our `doSomething` function will be triggered.

Comment: Hi Jonathan, thanks a lot for your suggestion - it works fine indeed. The second problem, however, remains open: How can I find out which of the 15 a elements did fire the event? Do you have any good idea about this? Dieter

Comment: @DieterProfos Within the callback (`doSomething` in this case) the keyword `this` refers to the element that raised the event. So to get the `className` of the link that was clicked, you would call `this.className`.

Comment: Hi Jonathan, thanks once more for your hint: It works perfectly! Dieter

Comment: @DieterProfos If this answered your question, please consider accepting it for the benefit of others in the future.

Comment: Sorry for the naive question: What should I do to 'Accept? Is there a dialog somewhere? Or is that the 'share | edit' remark?

Answer (score 0):

What you want to use is the .live function.

http://api.jquery.com/live/

You will not need to set up this function on each object.  Outside of your displaydata function you will want something like:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $(".reg_footnote").live('click', function() {
        //click event code
    });
});
```

Comment: The `.live` method is deprecated.

Comment: Wow, I had absolutely no idea.  Thanks for your comment, I'm going to have to change a lot of code!  :)

Comment: Hi Dale, thanks for your suggestion. This is more or less what I did in line 6 of my code snippet. However, the problem is how to introduce the identity of the &lt;a&gt; into the event handler function. Any good proposals for that?